# How the Lambda in static method instantiates the interface

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I've been doing java for some time, due to corporate and personal inertia, mostly java 1.7.
Recently I decided to start learning a bit more about the functional side o java, so I started playing  with the Function interface and building a **Validator** that would check **if a Map would match the Validator criteria**.
So that the Validator could be built programatically like

```
Usage:

Map<String, String> book = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

book.put("Title", "Leviathan Wakes");
book.put("Subject", "A proto molecule");
book.put("Category", "sci-fi");
book.put("TotalPages", "350")

final ResourceValidator filter = ResourceValidator.containsProperty("Title").and(ResourceValidator.containsProperty("Category"));
assert filter.apply(book);
```

This is code I've produced

```
    public interface ResourceValidator extends Function<Map<String,String>,Boolean> {
    
    static ResourceValidator containsProperty(String property) {
            return resource -> resource.containsKey(property);
        }

    default ResourceValidator and(ResourceValidator other){
        return resource -> this.apply(resource) && other.apply(resource);
    }
}
```

So far it seems to be behaving as expected, what I can't understand is how  the interface gets instantiated.
The call to

```
final ResourceValidator filter = ResourceValidator.containsProperty("Title");
```

calls static method of the interface, **how and where in the static method is ResourceValidator  instantiated?**

```
static ResourceValidator containsProperty(String property) {
            return resource -> resource.containsKey(property);
        }
```

I've been looking and I'm struggling to find an answer

Comment: When the _lambda expression_ is evaluated, an instance of the `ResourceValidator` interface is created as the result.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-
This is where I'm getting confused, I'm struggling with the concept.
Interfaces don't have constructors because they are Interfaces, yet as you are saying when the lambda expression is   evaluated the interface is created.
Is this just something I have to accept in java 8?

Comment: _Interfaces_ don't have constructors, but _objects_ do, and you use that all the time. The lambda expression creates _an object_ (via some magic means not specified) that implements that interface.

Comment: Creating an instance of an interface implementation without declaring a class, [is possible since JDK 1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). The difference is, lambda expressions 1) have a simpler and concise syntax, 2) provide compile-time type safety, and 3) are more efficient in most cases. But they can only implement functional interfaces, that are interfaces declaring only a single abstract method that does not match a public method of java.lang.Object [(see also this)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided the implementation of those static methods. For example; when you created a lambda as `resource -> resource.containsKey(property)`, what you essentially did was;

```
 return new ResourceValidator() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Map<String, String> resource) {
                return resource.containsKey(property);
            }
        };
```

you implemented the `apply` of `ResourceValidator` function (is subtype of `Function` interface, which is marked as a functional interface).

So now you could invoke it like;

`ResourceValidator.containsProperty("foo").apply(Map.of("foo", "bar"));`

You may have come across Java lambda expressions. Otherwise, this is quite comprehensive https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html,

Comment: Brilliant, thanks that makes a lot of sense and my question a lot more ridiculous.

Comment: No problem, if you use Intellij (not sure how Eclipse etc do) you could play around and see different variations of the same implementation of lambdas, method references etc.  Just press Option/Alt + Enter on the lambda for instance, which is called intention actions.